# How to retrieve properties from deeply nested RxJS Observable response and display in Angular html template?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Ughh...

I'm brand new to Angular (about 2 weeks), and have been looking at RxJS examples on stackoverflow for days, and just cannot figure this out and am under time pressure at work.  I know this question has been asked before, and I tried many different examples, but am still stumped.  I have a small Angular application that makes a call to a RESTful API.  I would like to be able to extract the value "F86292" of the property "flagName" from the API response below:

```
{
    "headers": {},
    "body": [
        {
            "flagId": 2,
            "flagParentId": 0,
            "flagTypeId": 1,
            "flagName": "F86292",
            "flagDesc": null,
            "flagToggleState": 0
        }
    ],
    "statusCode": "OK",
    "statusCodeValue": 200
}
```

I can successfully make a call to the API service and retrieve the JSON above using the following code snippets below (omitted code denoted by ellipses):

```
interface ServerData {

  headers: Object;
  body: Array<any>;
  statusCodeValue: number;
  statusCode: string;

}


. . . 


  flagData$: Observable<ServerData>;

. . . 


    this.flagData$ = this.http.get<ServerData>(this.url, options).pipe(
      map(
        response =>
          ({
            headers: response.headers,
            body: response.body,
            statusCodeValue: response.statusCodeValue,
            statusCode: response.statusCode
          } as ServerData)
      )
    );
```

I can then display the values `statusCodeValue` and `statusCode` in my template html because they are first-level properties of the nested response object.  However, I am unable to retrieve "flagName" and other properties from the response body.

```
   <table *ngIf="flagData$ | async as flag">
      <tr>
        <td class="heading">
          Flag Id
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ flag.statusCode }}
        </td>
      <tr>
```

I have tried several examples out there that use pipe, map, etc. and just cannot make it work.

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you so much for your help!

Note:  Per Zircon's recommendations below, I changed ServerData above
FROM   `body: Object;`
TO     `body: Array<any>;`

This combined with his solution worked!  Thank you Zircon!! :-)

Comment: `.pipe(switchMap(x => x....))`? [More info](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flagData$` is an `Observable<ServerData>`. When you use the `async` pipe on it, the result is the data from the Observable, in this case a `ServerData` object.

This is why you can easily display the `statusCode` via `{{ flag.statusCode }}` in your template. But there are no nested `Observable`s in this object. Rather, the data you need is "nested" within inner objects of `flag`.

If you want to specifically show the value "F86292" from your response, the path to use in your template would be `{{ flag.body[0].flagName }}` because `flag.body` is an array.

If you wanted to display *each* `flagName` that could appear in that array, you could use `*ngFor`. Here is an example of showing some info of each element of `body` per row:

```
      <tr *ngFor="let bodyEl of flag.body">
        <td>{{ bodyEl.flagId }}</td>
        <td>{{ bodyEl.flagName }}</td>
      </tr>
```

The above code could be read as "for each element of `flag.body`, create a table row that shows its flag ID and name."

Comment: Thanks very much Zircon for your prompt reply, very much appreciated.  I tried your suggestions and they resulted in 2 compilation errors:

 error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'Object'.
  Property '0' does not exist on type 'Object'.

         {{ flag.body[0].flagName }}


error TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any> | null | undefined'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?

       <tr *ngFor="let bodyEl of flag.body">

Comment: @jeff in your `interface ServerData` try changing `body` from `Object` to `Array<any>`.